# firestore: user Array.includes with a DocumentReference

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm trying check if an array with DocumetReferences contains a specific ref.

That's my attempt:

```
const likedWorkouts = user.collection('additional').doc('liked');
const snapshot = await likedWorkouts.get();
const exists = snapshot.exists;
hasLiked = snapshot.data()?.liked?.includes(workout); // This part (workout is a DocumentReference)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#isequal) is an object and you cannot compare them directly. You can use the `isEqual()` method to compare the refs:

```
hasLiked = !!snapshot.data()?.liked?.find((likeRef) => likeRef.isEqual(workout));

// Alternatively, you can compare the paths
// likeRef.path === workout.path
```

The [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) in the new Modular SDK doesn't not have `isEqual()` method but instead there is a top level function `refEqual()`. It can be used as follows:

```
import { refEqual } from "firebase/firestore";

hasLiked = !!snapshot.data()?.liked?.find((likeRef) => refEqual(likeRef, workout));
```

Checkout [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality#comparison_of_objects) for more information on objects.

Comment: Why do you use !!snaphot.data().... (Why !!?)

Comment: @JaRoMaster `find()` returns the matched element found in the array. The `!` is [Logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) and I used it since you need a boolean value. Read more about that at the link.